# Why am I getting wrong count of number of existing files inside a directory using dirent?

Tags: c, count, dirent.h

I wrote a small function that receives a path of a folder and should return the number of files inside it.

For some reason my answer is not correct: When printing it I saw that it prints `.` and `..`.

Can someone tell me why? Would decreasing `2` solve it?

Here is the code:

```
    {
    struct dirent *entry;
    DIR *dirp;
    int fileCount = 0;
    char currPath[MAX_STR];
    dirp = opendir(clientLocalPath);
    printf(" ***** printing files!!!!! ********\n");
    while((entry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
    {
            strcpy(currPath, entry->d_name);
            printf("%s\n",currPath);
            fileCount++;

    }
    closedir(dirp);
    return fileCount;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C , readdir() beginning with a dots instead of files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265328/c-readdir-beginning-with-a-dots-instead-of-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal and it happens because both `.` and `..` are part of the directories: `.` refers to the current one and `..` to the parent.

From [What is a dot only named folder?](https://askubuntu.com/a/327178/143251):

> Every directory contains a `.` and a `..` entry.
>
> `.` means the directory itself. It is called the *current* directory.
>
> `..` means the directory's *parent directory*, that is, the directory
>   that contains it.

From [Why do directory listings contain the current (.) and parent (..) directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/322741/1983854):

> Best way is to just `strcmp` and ignore them, if you don't want to
>   list them.

Answer (score 2):

`.` is the current directory

`..` is the parent directory

These 2 names you will find in every folder while scaning for file. while getting files name you can ignore these two values by checking names in your code.

For example 
`"..\tmp.txt"` specifies a file named `tmp.txt` located in the parent of the current directory

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is perfectly normal. The `.` and `..` indicate current and parent directories respectively. If you want to ignore them and consider the rest of the files for your fileCount variable, you can do something like this:

```
while((entry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
{
    if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
                    printf("\0");
    else
    {
        strcpy(currPath, entry->d_name);
        printf("%s\n",currPath);
        fileCount++;
    }
}
```